# Wordpress save post action overwrites post meta update

Tags: php, wordpress, post, save, sql-update

When I am firing the following action hook on the post save without the exit, Wordpress is overwriting the values I set for some fields (not all). Especially the _variable_pricing key. When I set exit; after this function and prevent Wordpress to finish the whole action the field is correctly updated in the database. It seems there goes something wrong in the ordening I guess?

```
function edit_photo_meta($post_id)
{
    # Update meta
    //... other fields to update
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_variable_pricing', 1);
    exit;
}
add_action('save_post', 'edit_photo_meta')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possible the autosave.

Try

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
  return;
```

in the function edit_photo_meta

Comment: thank you for answering, the value of the key '_variable_pricing' still stay's '0'. When I do the exit; it stays on '1' but I break the function of course.

Comment: Do you have test to skip the Autosave of the post?

Comment: Yes I've added your code to the function for testing :) .. I tried on a post edit but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Probably the order of action hooks. You are better off hooking the updated meta:

```
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'override_post_meta', 10, 4 );
function override_post_meta( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, &$meta_value )
{
    if ( '_variable_pricing' == $meta_key ) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_variable_pricing', 1);;
    }
}
```

This hook is called **after** the meta is updated, so it overrides the previous value.

Comment: .. string(17) "_variable_pricing" .... int(1) ... is the var_dump output. It has been set but still in the database I have a 0 value. The hook seems to be to early and has been overwrite

Comment: I took a look at the code and updated the answer. It turns out that WordPress was ignoring the change. There is a hook with almost the same name name (updated with a d instead of update) with the same parameters. You can all that and actually update the meta like you tried before.